# Run a method or command when a row is expired Laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a table which has user publications, when the user publish a publications he choose a date that this publication will remains visible in the platform, i want a way to flip the state of a publication that time is come to now be shown anymore (date of publication is equal or greater then date system), i know about the `cronjob` way but i wanted to ask here if there's a better way to do this because i think the `cronjob` way is not good for this i will have to run a command every minute which i prefer not to do, i only need ideas not code.

Thank you.

Comment: If you just want to show this expire thing on front-end then you don't need any CRON, a simple calculation at the time of showing data will handle this. Otherwise you can create a CRON and run it only at 11:59 PM, there is no need to run this CRON on every minute.

Comment: You could write a background process that does the same thing

Comment: @MayankPandeyz i have to run the CRON every minute because the user choose the exact time his publication will stop appear in the platform, for the front-end proposition yes it will work but i prefer to remove those conditions from the views as much as i can.

Comment: @Thomas "background process" is a CRON

Comment: yes, but it will be more responsive than once a minute.

Comment: @Thomas it will be a lot of work for the database to go through all the publications all the time.

Comment: I agree, you might not have a lot of other options besides a cronjob then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not store an `active` flag on the database. In your case `active` is a derived attribute and derived attributes should not really be stored as columns, not to mention that since `active` will be based on a date it is not functionally dependant on the primary key directly so is also in violation of the 2nd normal form. These two reasons will generally lead to data anomalies and what you're trying to do with a scheduled task is basically hack your way around those anomalies.

My suggested approach is to use an eloquent model attribute and attribute mutators like below:

```
class Publication extends Model {
     protected $appends = [ 'active' ];

     public function getActiveAttribute() {
         return $this->activeUntil < Carbon::now(); //Still active
     }
}
```

This way your model includes the `active` attribute which is computed by eloquent and not stored in the database.